# How to insert json object to a column in postgres table using pyspark

Tags: json, postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json variable as below, i need to insert that to a particular column in a table in postgres. How do i go about it

JSON variable is man_j which is below format

```
     {"a_type":"Res", "display_type":"Res", "data_type":"AAA", 
     "source_name":"na", "li_details":{"li_value":"na", "li_column":"na"}, 
       "additional_info": {"d_name":"na",  
      "description":"na", "program":"program2",  
        "Author":"author2", "email":"na", "sum":"na", 
         "file_name":"na","additional_files":"na", "notify_email":"na"}}
```

I have a column in postgres table called man_de for which i need to insert the value

Comment: Can you paste a json with all the variables so its easy to tell you how extract what you want @sanjana

Comment: The json mentioned above needs to inserted to a particular column, The entire json is stored in a variable which needs to be inserted into that column

Comment: If there is no transformation required then its best you load the json directly just like you load all other data types with an INSERT. Dont see a use for pyspark here.

Comment: So, the json variable created is in pyspark, hence my script should load automatically the json in the next step to a column in my table in postgres

Comment: Convert the variable to a Dataframe. Write it to the table directly using df.write method.API documentation here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html for more on this.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct version of Postrgres JAR during the initialization

Comment: Thanks, but i need to write to an already existing table which has many columns, and i need to insert this json output only one particular column in that table

Comment: Where does the data for the other columns come from ? Do you write that too ? or its there already and you are just updating the json column alone

Comment: Yes i write the data for other columns, but only for one column it should be from this json object created in my previous step

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not provide single columns updates directly.Your solution might get complicated using a staging area (in the db level) and updating the json columns alone (which is bit complicated than your actual problem in hand).

As you own the data for other columns too, convert the JSON variable to a DF.
Combine it with the DF of other columns.Now you have something that you can directly append.

1. DF1 --> All other columns
2. DF2 --> JSON variable

Join DF1 AND DF2 (hope you have some sort of PK's to join)
Rearrange the columns to the order in your RDBMS table.
Write/Append it using df.write based on your needs

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is something you are looking for , assuming that you have your connection is configured with PostGre , then you can simply call below to perform any sql operation

```
df = df.withColumn("new_json_column", json_variable) // I am assuming here you have the correct schema or else you can create null column to ensure there is no schema mismatch
//to send only 1 transaction
df = df.show(1)



df.write.mode("append").jdbc(jdbcUrl, "db.table_name", connectionProperties)
```

Comment: It will be the existing column name in the table

Comment: Not an issue .. you can give the same column name

Comment: I'm getting AssertionError : col should be Column